# After providing DOCKER_HOST variable in docker the local image is not found

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a docker container locally, and the image is also on my machine.

I need to provide a DOCKER_HOST variable to my docker run command. However, once I provide it, my local image is not found. It was working before I started passing the DOCKER_HOST variable, and the image is still locally.

I'm a docker beginner, so I am not sure how does the DOCKER_HOST variable affect the docker run command, or where does it look for the image now.

This is the error message I get:

```
Unable to find image 'my_image:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my_image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

How can I solve the issue? Or how can I specify that the image can be found locally?

Comment: Please share more details, like the current configuration and possible error messages

Comment: "I need to provide a DOCKER_HOST variable": why?

Comment: @Henry that's a requirement from the script I'm running

Comment: Then make sure, the image is accessible on the host specified by DOCKER_HOST. Your container will run on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, I needed to build the image in the host specified in DOCKER_HOST